# The recipe in Orchard core doesn't show up on admin configuration menus

Tags: orchardcms, recipe

I have setup Orchard core 1.2.2 but items under the admin side bar 'Configuration > Recepies' always shows "Nothing here! There are no recipes for the moment."[Orchard recipe item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja6H1.png)

Then I try to add a test recipe with Recipes folder as the instructions of https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/latest/docs/reference/modules/Recipes/ still remain the same result. But the new recipe can show when I build a new sites.However, it still not showing under the admin configuration as before.
[orchard recipe during setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fj2W.png)

I try to use import JSON thru configuration menus but still nothing showing.

Please advise how I can solve the issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert however I have noticed today that it's better to create the OrchardCore CMS project by entering the commands as follows, which will yield a "more complete" installation/configuration initial page that includes the `Recipe` dropdown list along with the `Default Time Zone` dropdown, both of which are missing when adding the `OrchardCore.Application.Cms.Targets` Nuget to an empty ASP.NET .NET6 app. So the commands are (the `--logger serilog` is optional):

```
# mkdir MyCmsSite
# cd MyCmsSite
# dotnet new -i OrchardCore.ProjectTemplates
# dotnet new occms --logger serilog
```

As a result you will get a CMS site ready to be configured, just run "dotnet run".

You will also have the following project templates available in case you decide to create them later on:

```
Template Name             Short Name   Language  Tags                
------------------------  -----------  --------  -------------------- 
Orchard Core Cms Module   ocmodulecms  [C#]      Web/Orchard Core/CMS 
Orchard Core Cms Web App  occms        [C#]      Web/Orchard Core/CMS 
Orchard Core Mvc Module   ocmodulemvc  [C#]      Web/Orchard Core/Mvc 
Orchard Core Mvc Web App  ocmvc        [C#]      Web/Orchard Core/Mvc 
Orchard Core Theme        octheme      [C#]      Web/Orchard Core/CMS
```

Source: [Code Generation Templates](https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/dev/docs/getting-started/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

'Configuration > Recepies' only displays Recipes that are not setup recipes.

Also receipies tagged with hidden are also not visible in admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have never managed to get this to work correctly.

I've tried putting recipe files in:

1. A /Recipes folder in the OrchardCore web app
2. A /Recipes folder in a custom theme that my app uses
3. A /Recipes folder in an OrchardCore module that my app uses
4. /wwwroot/Recipes folder

My recipe never shows up in the Admin Recipes section.

Setup recipes that are put in the web app /Recipes folder are available when I try to create a new OrchardCore tenant, but regular recipes outside of some for the Blog theme never turn up.

I have no idea why that would be; I've dug into the code for OrchardCore a fair amount and it appears that it ought to work, but it does not.